# How to display .bib keys when citing in Sublime Text3

Tags: biblatex, sublime-text, latextools

I'm currently using LatexTools with Sublime Text 3, with biblatex/biber for bibliography. I have roughly 50 or so citation keys, and it's been a bit annoying having to type out the full key names whenever I cite the paper. Is there a way to have a tree pop-up of the citation keys in the IDE like it does with commands?

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! The question might find a faster answer on a latextools or sublime text forum. Do you mean there is no autocomplete when you start typing a `\cite{` command? From a quick search, it seems to be a built-in feature, e.g., (https://latextools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings/) says: "`cite_auto_trigger` (true): if `true`, typing e.g. `\cite{` brings up the citation completion quick panel, without the need to type `C-l,x`. If false, you must explicitly type `C-l,x`." I will have to install both to find out how to do it.

Comment: Addendum: Sublime Text looks very powerful (it uses Python) but TL;DS: too long, didn't start using it even after 1.5hr looking and clicking: since its setup and project toolchain methodology is nowhere clear or easy to find, and cryptic and counterintuitive, the answerbase population is likely to very narrow and specific, so the utility of any answer here is unlikely to be higher than minimal or negligible to readers. (For me, it would be easier to use a lookup list (say via a spreadsheet, the bib file itself, e.g.) if I had a set of unstructured random cite keys).

Comment: There is autocomplete, but just not when you choose one of the cite options. \ci will bring up the popup tree, and after selecting \cite{key}, there is no additional popup with a list of keys. Turns out if you type from scratch instead of choosing one from the initial autocomplete, it gives a list of the keys in the command prompt instead.

Comment: Useful to know. Sounds like it could be a bug.

Comment: The reason for the described behavior is that sublime text currently does not support a "on auto-completion inserted"-hook, therefore LaTeXTools can't hook into that event. Unfortunately this is not intuitive, but we don't see a way around it other then manually opening the fill all helper C-l, C-f or the auto completion pop-up C-space. The same holds for all other type of commands (references, environments, glossaries, and files)